# Convergence and differentiability of $\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\cos(\frac{x}{n})-1 $

Tags: derivatives, uniform-convergence, trigonometric-series

How to test the convergency of

$$\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)-1\right) $$

I know that after testing whether the sum is convergent (the function is well defined) I can test whether the sum of derivatives of partial sum is uniformally convergent, thus determine whether it is differntiable, however I am stuck on the convergence. I would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean $\sum \cos\left(\frac xn\right)-1$?

Comment: Therefore it isn't convergent, thus it isn't differentiable. However, how to prove it?

Comment: Oh my Goddness, you're right, Caffeine! I  will correct it.

Comment: On what set are you interested in convergence and differentiability?

Comment: x belongs to real numbers, however I didn't know how to find the proper symbol in MathJax

Comment: After differentiation, obtained a common term $-\frac{1}{n}\sin\frac{x}{n}$. So use the Weierstrass test for uniform convergence on arbitrary segment.

Answer (score 0):

$0\leq 1-\cos t \leq \frac {t^{2}} 2$ and $\sum \frac {x^{2}} {n^{2}}$ converge is uniformly convergent on  compact sets. Also the differentiated series is uniformly convergent on  compact sets (becasue $|\sin (\frac x n )|\leq \frac {|x|} n$). Hence the series converges to a  differentiable function.

I am using the following elementary fact:

If $s_n(x) \to f(x)$ uniformly on compact sets and If $s_n'(x) \to g(x)$ uniformly on compact sets  then $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=g(x)$.